# RSS Application Stops

Tags: android, parsing, casting, rss

I followed this RSS Reader [Tutorial](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/creating-a-simple-rss-application-in-android/).

So at first I got an error in this line:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(links.get(position));
```

I got the error, that i have to cast it to a String like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse((String) links.get(position));
```

after that it was possible to run the App.
But if I want to open a ListView Element the app is stopped every time....
Does anyone an idea of what's wrong?

and here the logcat:

```
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 0
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at com.rss_reader.MainActivity.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:111)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-20 19:25:19.027: E/AndroidRuntime(505):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

after i read the description i think the Uri is maybe null because:

Throws
NullPointerException  if uriString is null

but why its null? i have no idea...

edit: the link to the tutorial is the wrong... but now i found the right one.

Comment: Post your LogCat errors, so we can see what is happening. `links` isn't part of that tutorial... post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Thank you for updating the tutorial link. What URL are you trying to read? Does it have `links` data?

Answer (score 1):

The important information in your LogCat is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 0
```

which means your `links` list is *empty*, and then:

```
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
    at com.rss_reader.MainActivity.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:111)
```

You can see that you try to read a value from `links` (that doesn't exist) in your `onListItemClick()` method on line 111, which as you said above is:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse((String) links.get(position));
```

You **must** to add data to your `links` list with `links.add()` at some point...

Comment: `else if ( xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title") )
     {
      if ( insideItem )
       links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article 
     }`

thats the place where something should add to link.... but apparently it does not ...

Comment: With the updated tutorial link I found this code, but what URL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your culprit is here:

```
com.rss_reader.MainActivity.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:111)
```

in line 111, of MainActivity.java

**EDIT**

then it means you reaching outside your data, or more precisely

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 0
```

your `links` is empty while you try to get 3rd element of out it, hence IndexOutOfBounds exception. Check why `links` is not initialized correctly or do some other checks to ensure your `position` is set right for the environment.

Comment: thats this row:
Uri uri = Uri.parse((String) links.get(position));

Comment: nooo i got the error....
i´ve copy & pasted this if `else if ( xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title") ) { if ( insideItem ) links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article }` and forgot to change the "title" to "link"... now it works.... ohhh sry for the expense....